# Не происходит сравнение нескольких strpos()

Tags: php, условия

Как правильно поставить несколько условий strpos? В данный момент данный код не работает.

```
if(strpos($url_explode_result[0], 'wall') === false || strpos($url_explode_result[0], 'photo') === false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит "код не работает"? Выдёт ошибку? Возможно надо использовать stripos() - без учета регистра. И какая стоит задача на проверку условия? Возможно, что сравнивать надо не как "**ИЛИ**", а как "**И**"?

```
if(strpos($url_explode_result[0], 'wall') === false && strpos($url_explode_result[0], 'photo') === false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = 'vk-wall-post';
$explode_sign = '-';
$array = array("wall","photo");
if(0 == count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode($explode_sign, $string)), $array))){
  //
}
?>
```

Comment: @stck, ваш код вообще делает Ошибку сервера.

>> На веб-сайте произошла ошибка при получении http://url. Веб-сайт может быть закрыт на обслуживание или настроен неправильно.

Comment: @ModaL, смотря как применяете - что передаёте на обработку - какую строку и какие варианты и какой разделитеть